# how to get the first object of a for loop

Tags: python, list, object, for-loop

I have a for loop look like below:

```
for i,x in enumerate(urunler):
    if x['fiyat'] == eklenecek['fiyat'] and x['urunobegi'] == eklenecek['urunobegi']:
        print x['id']
```

And it outputs:

```
1
2
3
9
```

How can I select the first object of this list?

Comment: What does this have to do with Django?

Comment: Of what list? You're not generating a list, you're printing values.

Comment: I'm sure he just means of the values that are printed.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like the "for-if antipattern".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach would be:

```
first_value = None
for i,x in enumerate(urunler):
    if x['fiyat'] == eklenecek['fiyat'] and x['urunobegi'] == eklenecek['urunobegi']:
        first_value = x['id']
        break
```

It's set up so that if no items in the list satisfy the conditions, `first_value` will be set to `None`.

If you want to select the last one:

```
last_value = None
for i,x in enumerate(urunler):
    if x['fiyat'] == eklenecek['fiyat'] and x['urunobegi'] == eklenecek['urunobegi']:
        last_value = x['id']
```

However, a better solution would be to turn it into a list so you can select any index at will. That would best be done as a list comprehension:

```
lst = [x['id'] for x in urunler if x['fiyat'] == eklenecek['fiyat']
                       and x['urunobegi'] == eklenecek['urunobegi']]

# First element: lst[0]
# Last element: lst[-1]
```

Comment: what if I wanted to select the last one?